# Nuxt3 using typescript with useFetch and transform option

Tags: typescript, nuxtjs3

I'm using `useFetch` to fetch an array of strings `string[]` with the `transform` option to transform it from array to object.

I tried  the code below:

```js
type ReceivedData = [string, string, string];

interface TransformedData {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string,
    prop3: string
}

const { data, error } = await useFetch<ReceivedData>(
    `./jsonPath.json`,
    {
      transform: ([prop1, prop2, prop3]: ReceivedData): TransformedData  => ({
         prop1, prop2, prop3
      })
    }
);
```

I'm getting this error

`Type '([prop1, prop2, prop3]: ReceivedData) => TransformedData' is not assignable to type '(res: ReceivedData) => ReceivedData'.`

I pretty sure I'm messing something here, but Typescript is expecting the transform method to return the same data type it receives.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you could use it like this:

```js
  type ReceivedData = [string, string, string]

  interface TransformedData {
    prop1: string
    prop2: string
    prop3: string
  }

  const transform = ([prop1, prop2, prop3]: ReceivedData): TransformedData => ({
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3,
  })

  const { data } = await useFetch<
    ReceivedData,
    Error,
    string,
    ReceivedData,
    typeof transform
  >(`./jsonPath.json`, {
    transform,
  })
```

Honestly speaking, I hope this will be improved in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was omitting the generic from the `useFetch` call and assigning the expected response type to the `transform` param

```
const { data, error } = await useFetch(
    `./jsonPath.json`,
    {
      transform: ([prop1, prop2, prop3]: ReceivedData): TransformedData  => ({
         prop1, prop2, prop3
      })
    }
);
```

Comment: But then my data type if `globalThis.Ref<any>`